# Change color of day name from php date() output

Tags: php, css

I use php's date() function to print date on site.

```
echo date('l, M j, Y H:i');
```

It displays output like this.

```
Tuesday, Oct 16, 2012 10:13
```

How to change the color of 'Tuesday' alone to red color. I couldn't find a way to apply CSS to 'tuesday' alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do this.

```
<?php
$var=date('l');
?><font color="#567890"> <?php echo $var; ?></font>
```

Comment: That's not applying CSS, that's using a `font` tag. The `font` tag has long been deprecated: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/graphics.html#h-15.2.2

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to do that in pure CSS, you need to wrap "Tuesday" in a HTML tag so that it can be individually styled in CSS. You'll need to adjust your PHP to do something like this,

```
echo "<span class='day'>" . date('l') . "</span>" . date(', M j, Y H:i');
```

Then you can just style the span as normal in CSS,

```
span.day { color: #f00; }
```